# rpg as400 headings print 2x?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpg

the headings print at the begining and at the end of the report. i think my LR is wrong. any help?

```
ft1prlc    if   e             disk
fqsysprt   o    f  132        printer
d heading1        c                   'Salary Report'
d heading2        c                   'SSN      Last Name    Salary'
c                   read      t1prlc                                 lr
c                   dow       *inlr=*off
c                   except    printline
c                   read      t1prlc                                 lr
c                   enddo
oqsysprt   H                           2
O                                              Heading1
O          h                           2
O                                              Heading2 
oqsysprt   e            printline      2
```

Answer (score 1):

To RPG, there isn't any real distinction between record types "H" and "D".  Both are processed the same.  To understand why you're getting your heading lines twice, you need to understand the RPG logic cycle.  In short, the logic cycle starts by printing heading & detail lines before doing any c-spec calculations.  Then it prints any heading & detail lines after each time through the logic cycle.  So we have:

1. Print headings and details
2. Check *INLR. If *ON, then end.
3. Perform detail calculations
4. Go back to step 1

To prevent this, your F-spec should designate an overflow indicator.  Then your O-specs should be conditioned using the same overflow indicator.

Comment: Also, even following that advice, your headings will only ever print once because you aren't really using logic cycle programming.  Now, I'm not saying that you should use logic cycle programming.  In fact, few people do anymore.  You should make your heading lines part of the same execpt print group as the detail line, but with overflow indicators.  This way, if there is a page break, you'll get new headers, too.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to RPG!

Do you see how the exception print is set to happen on a certain condition?  The details will only print when the EXCEPT operation specifies PRINTLINE.  If you had another EXCEPT for say, PRINTLINE2, PRINTLINE would not print.

What is conditioning your heading lines?
Hint: 'H' lines are conditioned with indicators, not with names like PRINTLINE.